# Compare lines from streaming API - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stream, compare, store

I am lost here, I have an API that streams prices, I am trying to compare the second to last price with the last price, for instance, if x > y then do something.  I cannot figure out how to compare the last to the second to the last price when the prices are streaming.  Could someone please shed some light on how this may work?  Thanks in advance!

my stream:

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
        response = self.connect_to_stream()
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return

        for line in response.iter_lines(1):
            if line:
                try:
                    msg = json.loads(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                    return
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    price = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                    print price
```

This prints a price like 1.23004 and then continues to loop and print more prices.  I have tried to save the current price in a variable outside the loop and then reference it when a new price comes in but it's not working..

my attempt:

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
        response = self.connect_to_stream()
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return
        oldLine = ''    
        for line in response.iter_lines(1):
            if line:
                try:
                    msg = json.loads(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                    return
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    price = msg["tick"]["ask"]

        oldLine = price
        newLine = oldLine 
        if newLine > oldLine:
            print newLine
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1- Your indentation is a bit off as the comparison should be done inside the 'for' loop. In your case, the comparison is only being made when the streaming is complete.

2- You are comparing oldLine with newLine which are equal, so nothing will happen. Instead you should compare newLine with price.
Consider the following code:

```
for line in response.iter_lines(1):
        if line:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return
            if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                price = msg["tick"]["ask"]

        oldLine = price
        newLine = oldLine 
        if newLine > price:
            print newLine
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, it doesn't seem to compare the prices when I run it inside the loop, in fact It doesn't let the streaming price through when we do that as I assume 'oldLine' and 'newLine' are seen as the same price?

Comment: Should I be trying to add the prices to a list and compare them that way?

Comment: Oh, you are comparing newLine with oldLine which are equal, so nothing will happen! Instead, you should compare newLine with price and you will get the desired response.

Comment: For some reason I am still not getting anything, i see what you are talking about though..